# Error converting value JSON to type Entity asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json

I have to request a `JSON` like this one:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "listEstoqueProduto": [{
            "codigoProduto": 0,
            "codigoGrupo": 0,
            "codigoSubgrupo": 0,
            "codigoInternoProduto": 0,
            "sequenciaCadastroSubGrupo": 0,
            "codigoProdutoCompleto": "string",
            "codigoCorProduto": 0,
            "descricaoVendasProduto": "string",
            "descricaoGrupo": "strimng",
            "descricaoSubgrupo": "string",
            "descricaoCategoriaProduto": "string",
            "descricaoFabricante": "string"
        }]
    }]
}
```

But when I try to read return this error: Error converting value `myJSONrequest` to type `ListaProdutos`
This is my code:

```
var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp("JSONurl");
requisicaoWeb.Method = "GET";
using (var resposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
{
    var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
    object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Resultado post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resultado>(objResponse.ToString());
    streamDados.Close();
    resposta.Close();
}
```

And those are my entities:

```
public class Resultado
{
    public ListaProdutos[] result { get; set; }
}

public class ListaProdutos
{
    public DualProdutos[] listEstoqueProduto { get; set; }
}

public class DualProdutos
{
    public int codigoProduto { get; set; }
    public int codigoGrupo { get; set; }
    public int codigoSubgrupo { get; set; }
    public int codigoInternoProduto { get; set; }
    public int sequenciaCadastroSubGrupo { get; set; }
    public string codigoProdutoCompleto { get; set; }
    public int codigoCorProduto { get; set; }
    public string descricaoVendasProduto { get; set; }
    public string descricaoGrupo { get; set; }
    public string descricaoSubgrupo { get; set; }
    public string descricaoCategoriaProduto { get; set; }
    public string descricaoFabricante { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Fabio yes, i'm sure, when i debug the code i can see the json data and it's corect

Comment: Error message is pretty clear: _Error converting value 'myJSONrequest' to type ListaProdutos_  - which can mean that "result" array do not contain item of proper json object format (`"{ }"`) but just a string "myJSONrequest"

Comment: @Fabio so this is a problem in the `json`code?